# Search for pattern in column data from csv file

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with data like below

```
SYMM_ID         DATE                    INSTANCE            Total Response Time
297900076   01-06-2022 05:00    SG_SG_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF  0.31
297900076   01-06-2022 05:05    SG_SG_ORACLUL_L_NPRDPRF 0.5
297900076   01-06-2022 14:50    SG_SG_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF  0.62
297900076   01-06-2022 14:55    SG_SG_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF  0.53
297900076   01-06-2022 15:00    SG_SG_ORACLUL_K_PRDPRF  0.61
297900076   01-06-2022 15:05    SG_SG_ORACLUL_M_PRDPRF  0.7
..............
```

I need to search for below patterens and fetch only the rows having these matching patterns

```
o   SG_SG_xxxxxxxx_L_NPRDPRF
o   SG_SG_xxxxxxxx_L_NPRDSTD
o   SG_SG_xxxxxxxx_L_PRDPRF
o   SG_SG_xxxxxxxx_L_PRDSTD
```

I was trying `-match`, but that not seems to be working

```
$GetData = Import-Csv -Path "C:\DIAG_2.csv" | Select SYMM_ID,DATE,INSTANCE,'Total Response Time'

$Local_Data = $GetData | where {($_.INSTANCE -match '_L_NPRDPRF') -and ($_.INSTANCE -match '_L_NPRDSTD')}
```

Please let me know how to do this

Comment: I quess you want to do an `-or`, (not `-and`) the same property can never match two different values...

Comment: have you tried -like?

Comment: @iRon: It will be `-and` because all the 4 patterns I have to match

Comment: @bpfrd: Yes. but my issue is I am not getting how to put it in the `where` condition which will match something like `SG_SG_*_L_NPRDPRF`

Comment: @EmptyCoder - per @iRon's comment, you almost definitely want ```-or``` instead of ```-and``` because ```-or``` means "if one of the left *or* right expression matches", whereas ```-and``` means "only if both left *and* right expressions match". To see this, run the following at a PowerShell prompt ```("SG_SG_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF" -match "_L_PRDPRF") -or ("SG_SG_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF" -match "_L_NPRDPRF")```, and then replace ```-or``` with ```-and``` and compare the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regex like `'^SG_SG_.+_L_N??PRD(?:PRF|STD)$'`.

Using your example data:

```
$Local_Data = $GetData | Where-Object { $_.Instance -match '^SG_SG_.+_L_N??PRD(?:PRF|STD)$' }
```

will return

```
SYMM_ID   DATE             INSTANCE                Total Response Time
-------   ----             --------                -------------------
297900076 01-06-2022 05:00 SG_SG_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF  0.31               
297900076 01-06-2022 05:05 SG_SG_ORACLUL_L_NPRDPRF 0.5                
297900076 01-06-2022 14:50 SG_SG_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF  0.62               
297900076 01-06-2022 14:55 SG_SG_ORACLUL_L_PRDPRF  0.53
```

Regex details:

```
^                 Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
SG_SG_            Match the characters “SG_SG_” literally
.                 Match any single character that is not a line break character
   +              Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
_L_               Match the characters “_L_” literally
N                 Match the character “N” literally
   ??             Between zero and one times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
PRD               Match the characters “PRD” literally
(?:               Match the regular expression below
                  Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      PRF         Match the characters “PRF” literally
   |              Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      STD         Match the characters “STD” literally
)                
$                 Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but I have to match `SG_SG_xxxxxxxx_L_NPRDPRF`. In my example I mentioned `_L_NPRDPRF` because I am not aware how to match first part `(SG_SG_)` and last part `(_L_NPRDPRF)`. the data mentioned as `xxxxxx` can be anything. and also in your solution you gave for the first 2 patterns, how to add the other 2 patterns in that?

Comment: @EmptyCoder Ah, I didn't thing the `SG_SG_` was important. Please see my edited answer. Also, the regex matches all example patterns, not just the first two..